# Athena SQL Case When Issue

Tags: sql, case, amazon-athena

I just started learning AWS Athena and I want to group date strings into intervals but my case statements aren't working. I'm basically trying to create buckets.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
Select 
Case time
WHEN time between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('03:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '12AM - 3AM'
WHEN time between date_parse('03:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('06:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '3AM - 6AM'
WHEN time between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '6AM - 9AM'
WHEN time between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '9AM - 12AM'
WHEN time between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '12PM - 3PM'
WHEN time between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '3PM - 6PM'
WHEN time between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '6PM - 9PM'
WHEN time between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '9AM - 12AM'
END AS
Time_Intervals
From "another_db"."clean_crime_data" Order by time limit 10;
```

I've updated the query and receiving

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:11: Cannot check if varchar is BETWEEN timestamp and timestamp
```

I think I understand the issue now.

The values are strings; therefore; how would it know what's between 12:00:00 AM and 03:00:00 AM.  Any ideas on a workaround?

Here is what I have now.

```
Select 
Case 
WHEN date_parse(time,'%h:%i:%s %p') between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('03:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '12AM - 3AM'
WHEN date_parse(time,'%h:%i:%s %p') between date_parse('03:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('06:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '3AM - 6AM'
WHEN date_parse(time,'%h:%i:%s %p') between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '6AM - 9AM'
WHEN date_parse(time,'%h:%i:%s %p') between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '9AM - 12AM'
WHEN date_parse(time,'%h:%i:%s %p') between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '12PM - 3PM'
WHEN date_parse(time,'%h:%i:%s %p') between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '3PM - 6PM'
WHEN date_parse(time,'%h:%i:%s %p') between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '6PM - 9PM'
WHEN date_parse(time,'%h:%i:%s %p') between date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') AND date_parse('12:00:00 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') Then '9AM - 12AM'
END AS
Time_Intervals
From "another_db"."clean_crime_data" Order by time limit 10;
```

The error message is : Amazon QuickSight can’t parse the data because it contains invalid dates or invalid numbers. Make sure your data contains only supported number and date formats.

Comment: `Case when time between ... then ...`. BTW, case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: And you have a missing `"`.

Comment: LIMIT but no ORDER BY will give you some random rows. As meant?

Comment: if you stored your time data as a string it is basically impossible to do time based operations on them -- first convert time column to hours and minutes -- then you can perform the logic on those columns

Comment: I tried to convert the time using date_parse(time,'%h:%i:%s %p')